# how to remove a few lines from a Unicode registry file using batch commands in Windows?

Tags: unicode, cmd, batch-processing

I have a program who's generating some data in registry.
I save it with "reg export HKCU\Software\ProgramName\Data data.reg" (Unicode format).
I need to take it to other computer and import it there so the program from that computer could use the data.
But I have to remove some text lines from data.reg. The text lines are easy to find because they contain some strings (for example paths to exe and dlls, specific program settings like "name1=value1", "name2=value2",...).
Now I'm doing this manually (using Wordpad) every few days but maybe there is another way...
Oh and I can't install other programs on these computers (the access is restricted) so I have to use batch/cmd files.
What I tried so far:
- redirecting the export to "con" but is visual only not in a variable;
- using "for /F ..." but this works only with ANSI and removes blank lines.

The lines must be removed before importing because the settings of the program from the first computer must not be loaded into the registry keys of the program from the second computer.

Can somebody please help me...?
Thank you.

Comment: it'd help if you specified what strings are to be removed. Just some example of before and after the removal so we can have an idea of what to remove

Comment: For example the path to the program (exe, dlls)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to loop the file contents line by line

```
FOR /F %z IN (yourfile.reg) DO ...
```

Then use conditionals to determine if this line is one you want to keep

```
IF (%z)==[put your key string here]
```

If so (or if not), then write that variable to the target file

```
@echo %z >> output.reg
```

You can replace the filenames with command line arguments, use %1, %2, etc.

All together, then:

```
    FOR /F %z IN (%1) DO IF NOT (%z)==[skip this line] @echo %z >> %2
```

Since you didn't give some critical details, I am making some assumptions here.  Further reading can be found at this excellent resource: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Comment: Thank you. But I mentioned why I can't use "for /F": because it works only with ANSI and the file is Unicode and it removes blank lines. A few days ago I tried "FOR /F %z IN (yourfile.reg) DO ..." but the file is not even processed... And which critical details are you referring to..?

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes.  Try using 'type' to change the encoding?  I'd recommend experimenting first, to ensure that it does not adversely affect the registry data or keys.  Your command is "type srcfile > destFile'.  If it works out, you could do it right at the top of the batch.

Comment: Yes, I know about the conversion but unfortunately it can't be used. The data is indeed Unicode...

Comment: Have you tried this when accessing the command shell using "cmd /u"?

Comment: No, because I never heard of it... But I tried now "cmd /u" and then running the "for ...". Same result, the reg file isn't processed.

Comment: Try that again with uppercase U... my bad.  But, I'm not hopeful.  How about changing code pages?  Yikes!  If that's your ticket, I'm afraid I'm not much use there.

Comment: No change with U... You're talking about changing code pages in batch file or in Control Panel..? In batch file I don't know how to do that and if is gonna help (since the data in Unicode)...

Comment: chcp /? for the help page.  BE. CAREFUL.  :)

Comment: Ok. On those computers the code page is 852. Which value should I use, 850? And I still don't understand how this is gonna help me...

Comment: You can change the codepage, which will alter how the `type` command handles the unicode, then do your FOR /F.  I am not able to advise you further on that score and suggest research, trial and error are in your near future.  Or, someone else here may come in and make us both look like noobs.  :)

Comment: Yes, the conversion... But if I mess up something in the data, I'll lose not only my job :D So I need to be 100% sure that the conversion is working...

Comment: Extensive testing is the only way to ensure that it will be reliable.  To be honest, if it is truly THAT critical, I do not recommend using DOS batch files at all.  This is something of a hack.

Comment: Yes, you have a point but I will still gonna try to find a solution. Oh, after changing the code page, is there any direct way (not through a file) to redirect the output of "reg export" into the input of type?

Answer (score 0):

An example would be nice, but could you use `reg delete` to delete the keys/values you want after importing your .reg file?

Comment: It is a good idea but I remove those lines so some settings of the program from the first computer could not be transferred to the program on the second computer, only data. So those lines must be removed before importing. Sorry for not been more specific about that in my question.